# Mempool contains transactions with gasPrice lower than baseGasPrice. WTF?

Tags: hardhat, bsc, txpool

When I look on https://bscscan.com/gastracker I see the next picture:
[image]

The network gas price is 3 Gwei, but in mempool(as I understand the chart on the left represents mempool state) appears transactions with lower gas price (1Gwei)
A random transaction from one of the top gas guzzlers
https://bscscan.com/tx/0x18b974fd960e8850403bd7221f85a1766f8cd4d073d89ec2e2bf50a641d801c3

as you can see it was mined 3 mins ago and the gas price was 1.02 Gwei

[image]

If I try to send a transaction with gasPrice: 1.02Gwei, then I got the next error message `transaction underpriced`

The question is How transactions with gasPrice 1.02 Gwei are mined when the base network gas price is 3 Gwei?